# Pentagonal-Triangular numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Pentagonal Triangular Number is a number which is simultaneously a pentagonal number $P_n$ and triangular number $T_m$ . Such numbers exist when
$$
\frac{1}{2}n(3n-1) = \frac{1}{2}m(m+1)
$$
This problem boils down to the pell-like quadratic Diophantine equation:
$$
x^2-3y^2 = -2
$$
Using Brahmagupta's Lemma: 
$$
\text{Theorem 2.22 (Brahmagumpta)}\;\; \text{If }\; u^2 − Pv2 = k \;\; \text{ and } \;\; r^2 − Ps^2 = l \;\;\;\text{then} (ur ± Pvs)^2 − P(us ± vr)^2 = kl.
$$
One can prove that there are infinitely many $(n,m)$ such that $P_n = T_m$

(I did this around $3$ years back for extra credit in my number theory class)

I was just wondering if there were already papers or instances where somebody already showed this. 
 
Thanks.

#### EDIT

I explicitly ask for papers here and *not* websites where they discuss the general topic. I'm looking for a formal proof of something I've already witnessed so that I may compare their methodology with mine.

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PentagonalTriangularNumber.html

Comment: According to this page, there are recursive formulas for the $n$th Pentogonal-Triangular number.  I do not see an upper limit on these formulas, so I assume this implies that there are infinitely many such numbers, right?  http://oeis.org/A046174

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've seen that page...that is true, but I do not see an explicit proof on that page.

Comment: @anorton I'm looking for _papers_ or _instances_ where someone came up with a proof, like I did. I'd like to know where these formulas came from if you will.

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour I do not know where the formulas came from, nor am I contesting that there has been a rigorous, published proof of the existence of infinitely many such numbers.  I just wanted to bring that page to your attention.  Searching the author's names in journals *could* lead to a published source.  Not sure, nor do I have the time to really look deeply.

Comment: @anorton Hey, I'm sorry. Thank you. It's not you, (Several people have just pointed to that site when I've already seen it). I appreciate your desire to help me, thank you again.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say I don't know the answer to this offhand: is there a straightforward way to take two different recursive formulas and turn them into a recursive formula that gives their intersection? E.g., is it straightforward to take the recursive formula for pentagonal numbers and the one for triangular numbers and find the one for pentagonal-triangular numbers? [I'm guessing not, since finding the perfect squares in the Fibonacci sequence turned out to be a nontrivial problem.]

Comment: One could just define sequences of integers $x_k$ and $y_k$ by $$ x_k + y_k \sqrt{3} = (1+\sqrt{3}) (2 + \sqrt{3})^k$$ and note that $x_k^2-3y_k^2=-2$.

Comment: Ristyn, if you don't want people to tell you about webpages and things you already know about, the thing to do is to include that information when you first post the question. That also stops others from wasting their time finding things you already know about. That said, have you followed all the links on the wolfram and oeis pages to see whether any of them point to proofs? And that said, even if I can't point to a page where it was explicitly done, solving $x^2-3y^2=-2$ is standard stuff, I'm sure it has been done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's "Rustyn", and I would've hoped that the mathematical community wouldn't be posting _wolfram_ links as a reference when I _explicitly_ ask for papers or instances. My question is _very_ clear here. But I see your point.

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour Re-read my comment; you have apparently responded to something else.